# How interpret this C++ class declaration I found in a source?

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I'm going through a piece of C++ source code for a personal project I'm working on and I can't for the world figure out what's happening in the following snippet:

```
Event EV_ScriptThread_Execute(
    "execute", EV_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL, "Execute the thread."
);

class ScriptThread : Listener
{
    { &EV_ScriptThread_Execute, Execute },
    { NULL, NULL}
};

void ScriptThread::Execute(Event *ev)    
{
    //Stuff
}
```

As far as I can interpret, it creates an instance of the Event-class and stores it in `EV_ScriptThread_Execute`. It then defines the ScriptThread-class, but I have no idea how to interpret the line after it.

Could someone explain me what happens? How would `{ &EV_ScriptThread_Execute, Execute },` look like if it was written in full, and not, as it seems, a short-hand notation.

EDIT:
Apparantly I misintepreted the macro-definition which I thought would produce: `class ScriptThread : Listener`, based on all the replies I went back and found out it actually construct an array of some sort. It still kind of leaves me in the dark on what happens... as I can't actually compile the code (since it's just a snippet), I can't really look at the precompiled files either.

What is the result of this?

```
ResponseDef<ScriptThread> ScriptThread::Responses[] =
{
    { &EV_ScriptThread_Execute, Execute },
    { NULL, NULL}
};
```

Another EDIT:
So I found ResponseDef is a struct which looks like this:

```
template< class Type >
struct ResponseDef
{
    Event *event;
    void (Type::*response)(Event *event);
};
```

Conclusively this means the array gets filled up with a structure which takes both a pointer to an instance of `Event` as well as a pointer to a method, which would explain the initializer!

Thanks to everyone for brining me back on track!

Comment: It seems to me like an initializer list. Can you show the definition of Lister class ? But as Sebastian suggested, it can be a macro as well. Generate the preprocessed file to get the idea.

Comment: @Mahesh It looks incredibly like an initializer list to me, too.
I'm a bit skeptical concerning his snippet.  It starts out like
a class definition, but there is no production in the C++
grammar that would allow the opening `{` of a class definition
to be followed by a second `{`.  Even if `Listener` is a macro,
it would have to complete the class definition, and start a data
definion, for there to be any chance of this being legal.

Comment: Updated post, I misinterpreted the initial macro, but it still kind of leaves in the dark on what happens. Not so much the macro itself, but how `{ &EV_ScriptThread_Execute, Execute },` fits into an array...

Comment: Solved it, thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for a macro definition for Listener. I'm pretty sure that something horrible is hiding behind that. There is no other way to turn this snippet into something a C++ compiler will accept.

I expect something like:

```
#define Listener ScriptBaseClass { void Execute(Event *ev); } the_script[] =
```

Comment: I tried looking for a macro definition, but couldn't find one, so I assumed it was perhaps some sort of C++ trick I didn't know off. I will try to search again using your example.

Comment: Compilers usually have a switch to produce precompiled code. You can pass that switch and look at the output to see what this expands to.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the longest single token, `EV_ScriptThread_Execute`, turns up this:

```
Event EV_ScriptDoor_DoInit( "doinit" );   
Event EV_ScriptDoor_SetOpenThread( "openthread" );   
Event EV_ScriptDoor_SetCloseThread( "closethread" );   

ResponseDef ScriptDoor::Responses[] =   
{   
    { &EV_ScriptDoor_DoInit,           ( Response )ScriptDoor::DoInit },   
    { &EV_Door_DoClose,                  ( Response )ScriptDoor::DoClose },   
    { &EV_Door_DoOpen,                   ( Response )ScriptDoor::DoOpen },   
    { &EV_ScriptDoor_SetOpenThread,           ( Response )ScriptDoor::SetOpenThread },   
    { &EV_ScriptDoor_SetCloseThread,          ( Response )ScriptDoor::SetCloseThread },   
    { NULL, NULL }   
};
```

From here: .htm">http://read.pudn.com/downloads99/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/406853/doors.cpp_.htm

It's clearly related code, and what is it from?  Quake 2.  So that's what we're looking at--for anything more detailed about how or why your specific bit of code works, we'd need to see (or find) more...and that may be a bit tricky given the revision history listed in the above file:

```
// 48    8/24/98 11:32a Markd   
// Added Start method to threads, repladed all ProcessEvent(   
// EV_ScriptThread_execute) with thread->Start( -1 )
```

Maybe someone else knows who Markd is; I don't.

Comment: It is indeed from a "drop-in" solution for Quake 3 based games, however, as I assumed it was a C++ syntax trick I didn't find it relevant to link to where it came from.

Comment: StackOverflow really needs the possibility to accept more than one answer, but thank you as well!